# What Edge(options = options) means in the MSFT Edge selenium documentation?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I  am having a lot of trouble understanding this line of code: `driver = Edge(options = options)`  from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=python.

I have already accomplished what I wanted to with Selenium but would like to understand the documentation to further my skills as a coder.

I have also done research and found this `driver = Edge(executable_path='where', options=edge_options)` from another stackoverflow question, which makes more logical sense.

`options = options` though...

Comment: `options = options` is exactly the same as `options=edge_options`, except the value you're passing as the keyword argument has a different name.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
driver = Edge(options = options)
```

this line is basically telling us that you are creating an `Edge` browser instance with an options, so what can be the options, right ?

let's say you do not wanna to open windows, and still wanna use Selenium, that would be a headless mode, how do we achieve that, the answer is using options.

```
options.add_argument("--headless")
```

Let's say you want to have a profile or bookmarks launched when you instantiate the browser driver how do we do that, the answer is using options.

How can we disable the extensions :

```
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
```

How can we set the windows size :

```
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
```

options are way to go with selenium, these are very few example that I have given you.

Read what official says :[here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.options)